# N2CMS single page layout not full width

Tags: .net, n2cms

Now i am new to .Net. I am using N2CMS here i face a problem for create a Full width`(100%)` single page layout. When i create a single page layout. The page was not full width, because this css was not change for the full with layout. Plz tell me how to create full width single page in N2CMS.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

N2CMS does not interfere with HTML nor CSS. So this problem comes down to actually using HTML with CSS to produce desired results.